# httpClient.execute gives back no response

Tags: java, android, https

I want to make a request to a page that contains a .csv file, get it back and parse it. I've been searching a lot and I found a lot of questions about accessing secure connections and stuff, but I think my problem is different. Below is my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {           

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://recursos-data.buenosaires.gob.ar/bicicletas-publicas/estaciones-bicis.csv");

        String text = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            Log.v("response code", response.getStatusLine()
                    .getStatusCode() + ""); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

When I debug it and get to the line HttpResponse response = httpClient... the program doesn't throw any exception but it doesn't keep on going either. It just hangs there. I don't know what the problem is. I've used this code before.

I'm using Android 2.2. Any ideas?

Comment: i never included the context when i used HttpClient. try it without it and see what happens.

Comment: I did but still the same problem.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm stuck with the same problem as the one you had!

Comment: No, I didn't. Is it a https or http connection in your case? I think the issue is related to that.